# profile_update not supplying old data

Tags: hooks

According to the WP documentation, the hook 'profile_update' fires after a profile is updated and provides the user id and the user object with the data BEFORE the update (I need both):

$old_user_data (WP_User) Object containing user's data prior to update.

However, when I try to access this, I get the new data and not the old.  Here's the code:

```
    add_action( 'profile_update', 'mgf_profile_update', 10, 2 ); 
    function mgf_profile_update( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {
    $member = get_userdata($user_id);
    echo 'old town ' . $old_user_data->country . '<br>';
    echo 'new town ' . $member->country . '<br>';
    die;
    }
```

In the test I made, a user's country (a custom field) was set to 'Italy' and I updated this to 'Italia'. The result was this:

old town Italia

new town Italia

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try creating `$member` _after_ you echo `$old_user_data->country`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but same result, I'm afraid.

Comment: I had the same problem. Turns out, the action was actually called twice, which meant that on the second call, the old data was equal to the new data.